# Can't iterate list after filter

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I run this code:

```
arr = list(filter(lambda x: x > 0, arr))
for index, item in arr:
  # do something
```

I get this error

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Which doesn't make sense because I have a `list` not an `int`.
Testing `arr` yields:

```
>>> print(arr)
[822]
>>> print(type(arr))
<class 'list'>
>>> print(len(arr))
1
```

Although there are plenty of questions regarding this type error here none explains this case.
What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: `for index, item in arr:` expects `arr` to contain pairs of items. Did you mean to do `for index, item in enumerate(arr):`?

Comment: Do you want to do “for index, item in enunerate(arr):”?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is not that `filter` is not iterable, but rather the fact that you do *iterable unpacking* in the head of the for loop:

```
for index, item in arr:
  # do something
```

Since the elements of `arr` are integers, you can not unpack them in two values (you write `index, item` as the "target" of the assignment, but how should Python solve `index, item = 1`?). You can use [**`enumerate(..)`**](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#enumerate) to keep track of the index:

```
for index, item in enumerate(arr):
  # do something
```

`enumerate(..)` takes as input an iterable, and produces an iterable of tuples where each tuple contains the *index* (as first item), and the element as second item. So `enumerate([1, 'a', 25])` will produce `(0, 1), (1, 'a'), (2, 25)`.

---

If you do not need the index, you can iterate over the `item`s without an `index`:

```
for item in arr:
  # do something
```

Comment: So there are different types of lists? Iterable and non-iterable?

Comment: @Razär: no. Al lists are iterable. But the *elements* of the list should be iterable in case you want iterable unpacking. In case you iterate over a list in Python, you *only* iterate over the *elements*. Not the index. In case you want the index as well, you can use `enumerate(..)`.

Answer (score 0):

If one has difficulty understanding `enumerate`, one can use following simple workaround:

```
arr = list(filter(lambda x: x > 0, arr))
for index in range(len(arr)):
    item = arr[index]
    # do something with item and index
```

I have not tested it but it may be more efficient than enumerate since it would avoid the overhead.

Comment: Note that in Python-3.x the outcome of `map` and `filter` are *iterables*, not `list`s, so as a result, you can not fetch `len(..)`, nor can you obtain `..[index]`. Although we can cast it to a list, it is perhaps worth adding this to the answer.

Comment: No, indirect iteration using an index from `range` is _less_ efficient than using `enumerate`.

Comment: I assumed `arr = list(filter(lambda x: x > 0, arr))` as given in the question. I have added it to my answer.